# AngularJS Caching on Website Deployment

Tags: angularjs, yeoman

I am currently using AngularJS with Yeoman to build websites. When changing HTML, CSS, and JavaScript, it seems my users browsers are caching the old version. Yeoman automatically renames JavaScript, and CSS file names, but for some reason the site is requiring they hit ctrl + shift + r to see the new files. This has caused numerous deployment headaches, and I was curious if anyone else has experienced this, and if anyone has any ideas on how to solve this problem.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

[Yeoman](http://yeoman.io/) will just setup the project for you, it will probably be using grunt or gulp to build the files as you mentioned.

Caching is handled both on the server and in the browser. It's likely your web server isn't invalidating the changes that you've made. You can try restarting the web server to fix this issue.

Comment: We are using Grunt to do builds. We are using IIS. Do you think restarting IIS on the site would solve the issue?

Comment: Yes, but a better way would be to manage the cache correctly in IIS try http://superuser.com/a/71885